# Putting Firebase Cloud Firestore Document fields into a card stack

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Collection of Documents and Im trying to get each Documents field "Name" into a card stack. The Collection is call "Users" and Documents are "userId". Each Document contains the field "Name" and "Gender" of that user. So far iv been able to get the currently signed in user's name to the card stack but am having issues getting the other users in the database to the stack. Here is the code Im using.Not getting any errors in the Logcat or experiencing any crashes.The data is just not being added. Any suggestions?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

TextView profileName,gender,StrangerName;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
FirebaseFirestore dataBase;
String userID;
ImageView ProfilePic;
private SwipeCardsView swipeCardsView;
private List<Model> modelList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override 
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    dataBase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    ProfilePic = findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
    StrangerName = findViewById(R.id.name);
    gender = findViewById(R.id.thisperson);
    profileName = findViewById(R.id.userName);

    //SwipeCards
    swipeCardsView = findViewById(R.id.swipeCardsView);
    swipeCardsView.retainLastCard(false);
    swipeCardsView.enableSwipe(true);

    getUserDB();
    getData();
    }
    // Method to get Users Documents
    private void getUserDB () {
        dataBase.collection("Users").get().addOnCompleteListener(new 
          OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        list.add(document.getString("Name"));
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, list.toString());

                    String strangers = list.toString();
                    StrangerName.setText(strangers);

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }});
        }
    // CardAdpater method
     private void getData() {
       modelList.add(new Model(StrangerName,ProfilePic));
          CardAdpater cardAdpater = new CardAdpater(modelList,this);
         swipeCardsView.setAdapter(cardAdpater);
      }
    private class CardStackTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
        @Override
        public void transformPage(@NonNull View page, float position) {
    }
    //Logout onClick
    public void LogOut(View view) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class));
        finish();
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to describe *exactly* what this code is supposed to do.  We should be able to trace the data from your source documents all the way to your views to see what might be happening.  Right now, we can't really see anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:  I used list to put all the names in. Feel free to ask anything :)

```
dataBase.collection("Users").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
            list.add(document.getString("Name"););
        }
        Log.d(TAG, list.toString());
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
    }
}});
```

Comment: That worked thanks man! What would be the best was to add those names to the TextView of a card?  I tried referencing the list but got a 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)'  error.

Comment: sorry for the late respond, its night here. Do you mean card view? your should use recycledView and in your adapter you should add a CardView.

Comment: The reason for your error is that you can't put CharSequence instead of String in your textView. You should use ".toString()" -> this should solve it. hope it help:)

Comment: No worries, its pretty late here too. I have a Card Adapter and a model for it, maybe there is an issue with my adapter. I  tried: String strangers = list.toString();
                                                                  StrangerName.setText(strangers); under the Log Tag list.toString(); and that was the error i received

Comment: I need more details about your adapter. And you didn't share you error log so i guess try to find answer for it in the search field or just ask a new question and i promise to look at it :)

Comment: I went ahead an posted a new question because I still cant figure it out lol. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60081740/adding-cloud-firestore-documents-into-an-arrayadapter